# How to get an string array from JSON arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, web-services

Well, I have a server response with this:

```
{
 cars =     (
 {
 "color" = red;
 "model" = ferrari;
 "othersAtributes" = others atributes;
 },{
 "color" = blue;
 "model" = honda;
 "othersAtributes" = others atributes;
 },{
 "color" = green;
 "model" = ford;
 "othersAtributes" = others atributes;
 },{
 "color" = yellow;
 "model" = porshe;
 "othersAtributes" = others atributes;
 }
 )
 }
```

I need a list of model cars. an array of models cars, to set to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to convert the raw response from the server to a Swift `Dictionary`.

```
let payload = [
  "cars": [
    [
      "color": "red",
      "model": "ferrari",
      "othersAtributes": "others atributes"
    ],
    [
      "color": "blue",
      "model": "honda",
      "othersAtributes": "others atributes"
    ],
    [
      "color": "green",
      "model": "ford",
      "othersAtributes": "others atributes"
    ],
    [
      "color": "yellow",
      "model": "porshe",
      "othersAtributes": "others atributes"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Then

```
let models: [String] = payload["cars"]!.map({ $0["model"] as! String })
print(models)
```

will give you `["ferrari", "honda", "ford", "porshe"]`.

(You might want to get replace the force unwraps `!` with safer error handling mechanisms.)

Comment: how I can convert? like this? `let payload = response as? [String: Any]` ?

Comment: I assume the server payload is in standard JSON form and you are requesting it using `NSURLSessionDataTask` so that you get a `Data` object. Then the answer will be what @Vignesh J posted. Although I'd recommend using `[String: Any]` to be more Swift-y. `let payload: [String: Any]= NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! [String: Any]`

Comment: I do it with alamofire

Comment: and response is a any object

Comment: You should be able to cast an `AnyObject` to a `Dictionary`. I think here is a perfect example https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/7f8fe9c7c69a958c279827f173e3b43a90f0c552/Tests/ResponseTests.swift#L351

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. Not tested perfectly. I am guessing cars is an Array:

```
 var modelsArray = [String]()
        for index in cars.enumerated(){
            let model = cars[index].value(forKey: "model")
            modelsArray.append(model)
        }
```